# read web.config from another assembly using t4

Tags: asp.net, class, t4, helper, connection-string

Does anyone have a good example or helper class that would allow me to read the connection string in a web application from a T4 template residing in ANOTHER assembly referenced by the web application. I am generating some code from the database that it references and i would appresiate some help on how to get the connection string for this use.
ive read George Js example [here](http://gcapnias.spaces.live.com/?_c11_BlogPart_BlogPart=blogview&_c=BlogPart&partqs=cat%3DT4%2520Templates) however it only works when the template resides in the web app, please help!!!

Comment: so let me see if i understand the scenario.. you have a web app. you have a template that you CAN modify but is compiled into separate referenced assembly. When you run the transform you want to be able to read the web.config of the referencing web app?  second detail needed: how are you running the template? interactively from VS or programmatically @ runtime?  If you can clarify these questions I am confident a simple solution is to be had.

Comment: You are spot on. the template is in a referenced assembly other than the actual web app, to answer your question at first just to be able to run it interactively at design time in vs.. for now. We are investigating a intergrated build, we have svn running and the constant modification of the templates connection string is driving us dilly (db is in app_data folder). im looking for a way to reference the db in the app_data folder using relative paths (or absolute) to get at the file itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var path = Host.ResolvePath(@"../Web.config");  
var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = path };           
var config =  ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
                                            map,ConfigurationUserLevel.None);  
var appSettings = config.AppSettings;  
var connectionStrings = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do something like that:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("../somePathTo/web.config")
// use the config to get values like: config.AppSettings
```

Comment: hey rob, the t4 template is run under a custom tool and therefore relative paths dont work as it is in the context of the tool not the project.

Comment: If you have calling Assembly, you could do sth. like that: 
New Uri(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath

This would only work, if you custom Tool uses API calls to excetue T4. 

May be your custom tool could provide some type of path parameter or could write the path info into some kind of shared data store. (XML-File of the excecuting directory)?

It would be nice to get more information.

Comment: this is the result of the above call to <#=System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase #>

file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.10.0/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.10.0.dll

Answer (score 0):

after a bit of searching around ive found my answer in t4 one may use

```
path = Host.ResolvePath(relativeFileName)
```